# Showing vectors are orthonormal

Tags: differential-geometry

Lets say I have a differential equation $$\frac{dx_i}{ds}=\sum^2 _{j=1} m_{ij} x_j $$
For $j=1,2,3$ and $m_{ij}$ is a skew symmetric matrix

Suppose vectors $x_1 (y_0), x_2(y_0), x_3(y_0)$ are orthonormal for for some $y_0$

How do you show that vectors $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are orthonormal for all values of $y$?

Comment: First, doesn't $j=1,2,3$? Second, it won't be true without some additional hypotheses on the $m_{ij}$. For example, if $m_{11}\ne 0$, then $\|x_1\|$ will never be constant.

Answer (score 1):

Write the equation in vectorial form as

$$ \dot{\vec{x}} = M\vec{x}. $$

If $\vec{x}_i$ are solutions to the differential equation, then

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left< \vec{x}_i, \vec{x}_j \right> = \left< \dot{\vec{x}}_i, \vec{x}_j \right> + \left< \vec{x}_i, \dot{\vec{x}}_j \right> = \left< M \vec{x}_i, \vec{x}_j \right> + \left< \vec{x}_i, M \vec{x}_j \right> = \left< \vec{x}_i, (-M) \vec{x}_j \right> + \left< \vec{x}_i, M \vec{x}_j \right> = 0 $$

where we used the fact that $M$ is skew-symmetric. Thus, if $\vec{x}_1, \vec{x}_2, \vec{x}_3$ are solutions of the equation and are orthonormal at some time $t_0$, they will be orthonormal for all $t$.